# Where can I find NTRU test vectors?

Tags: reference-request, ntru, test-vectors

In some research work in 2001, it is stated that test vectors were not publicly available at the time. Then in this ESSS1v2 standard under IEEE1363 [here](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/lattPK/submissions/EESS1v2.pdf) , the appendix B mentions that the test vectors will be added in future versions. I haven't found any. Where could I get the test vectors for NTRU?

Comment: https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto/blob/master/reference-code/Java/Encrypt/com/securityinnovation/testvectors/NtruEncryptTestVector.java

Comment: I've been looking for the test vectors also. https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto/blob/master/reference-code/Java/Encrypt/build.xml
refers to ""com.securityinnovation.testvectors.NtruEncryptTestVectorGenerator"
" I haven't looked any deeper than this, but it looks like they don't publish test vectors, but give you a means of generating them yourself

Comment: I click all links, but they are invalid. Who can give me a new? I want test vectors of NTRU.

Answer (score 2):

The most recent version of the paper indeed seems to be:

Efficient Embedded Security Standards (EESS)
EESS #1: Implementation Aspects of NTRUEncrypt and NTRUSign
Consortium for Efficient Embedded Security
June 20 th , 2003
Version 2.0

([PDF download](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/lattPK/submissions/EESS1v2.pdf))

Yet, as you stated, that doesn’t contain any test vectors; just like the previous (v1) paper:

> ### Appendix B - Test Vectors
>
> [To be added in future versions]

**But** you can find test vectors when checking implementations. For example, by looking at the files contained in the directory https://github.com/Yawning/ntru/blob/master/testvectors/

Alternatively, you could take a look at the files contained in the NTRUOpenSourceProject directory https://github.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto/tree/master/reference-code/Java/Encrypt/com/securityinnovation/testvectors/ (see [NtruEncryptTestVector.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NTRUOpenSourceProject/ntru-crypto/master/reference-code/Java/Encrypt/com/securityinnovation/testvectors/NtruEncryptTestVector.java) file)